# How can I process only the highlighted row using jquery?

Tags: jquery

so I have a list or records in a table that I append into another table on row click. So when I click on a row it get highlighted and I can add it to another table. The problem is that the appendTo function I have works off the row click event, but I want to process only the highlighted row.... Currently if I click on a row and then click another row it will process both the rows even if only one row is highlighted in my table.

Below is the Jquery Function with the 2 tables:

```
        $(document).ready(function () {

        $('#ProcessList_btn').hide();
        $('#CancelSelection').hide();
        $('#UpdateDBRecs').hide();

        $('.MatchedTransctions tbody tr').click(function (e) {

            $('.MatchedTransctions tbody tr').removeClass('highlighted');

            if ($(this).addClass('highlighted', function () {

                var $row1 = $(this).clone();
                var $chkbx = $('<td class="SelectedItemCHKBX"><input type="checkbox" id="SelectedItem" class="SelectedItem" /></td>');
                $('#ProcessList_btn').show();
                $('#CancelSelection').show();
                $('.SelectedtItemCHKBX').removeAttr('checked');

                $('#ProcessList_btn').click(function () {
                    $row1.prepend($chkbx);
                    $row1.appendTo('#SelectedForProcessing tbody');
                    $('#UpdateDBRecs').show();
                });

            }));

            $('#CancelSelection').click(function () {
                $('.MatchedTransctions tbody tr').removeClass('highlighted');
            });
        });
    })



    <div id="MatchedTransctions" class="MatchedTransctions">
    <table class="table">
        <thead>
            <tr>
                <th>
                    @Html.DisplayNameFor(model => model.Id)
                </th>
                <th>
                    @Html.DisplayNameFor(model => model.Region)
                </th>
                <th>
                    @Html.DisplayNameFor(model => model.Person)
                </th>
                <th>
                    @Html.DisplayNameFor(model => model.Item)
                </th>
                <th>
                    @Html.DisplayNameFor(model => model.Units)
                </th>
                <th>
                    @Html.DisplayNameFor(model => model.UnitCost)
                </th>
                <th>
                    @Html.DisplayNameFor(model => model.Total)
                </th>
                <th>
                    @Html.DisplayNameFor(model => model.AddedOn)
                </th>
            </tr>
        </thead>
        @foreach (var item in Model)
        {
            <tbody>
                <tr onclick="toggleClass(this,'selected');">
                    <td>
                        @Html.DisplayFor(modelItem => item.Id)
                    </td>
                    <td>
                        @Html.DisplayFor(modelItem => item.Region)
                    </td>
                    <td>
                        @Html.DisplayFor(modelItem => item.Person)
                    </td>
                    <td>
                        @Html.DisplayFor(modelItem => item.Item)
                    </td>
                    <td>
                        @Html.DisplayFor(modelItem => item.Units)
                    </td>
                    <td>
                        @Html.DisplayFor(modelItem => item.UnitCost)
                    </td>
                    <td>
                        @Html.DisplayFor(modelItem => item.Total)
                    </td>
                    <td>
                        @Html.DisplayFor(modelItem => item.AddedOn)
                    </td>
                </tr>
            </tbody>
        }
    </table>
    <div>
    </div>
</div>



    <div id="SelectedForProcessing">
    <table class="table" id="SelectedForProcessing">
        <thead>
            <tr>
                <th>
                    Select Record
                </th>
                <th>
                    @Html.DisplayNameFor(model => model.Id)
                </th>
                <th>
                    @Html.DisplayNameFor(model => model.Region)
                </th>
                <th>
                    @Html.DisplayNameFor(model => model.Person)
                </th>
                <th>
                    @Html.DisplayNameFor(model => model.Item)
                </th>
                <th>
                    @Html.DisplayNameFor(model => model.Units)
                </th>
                <th>
                    @Html.DisplayNameFor(model => model.UnitCost)
                </th>
                <th>
                    @Html.DisplayNameFor(model => model.Total)
                </th>
                <th>
                    @Html.DisplayNameFor(model => model.AddedOn)
                </th>
            </tr>
        </thead>
        <tbody></tbody>
    </table>
    <div>
    </div>
</div>
```

Comment: I have a class which I call when I click on a row to highlight that row. I want to append only the highlighted row. It will easy for the user to know that they are working with only the highlighted row.

Comment: the append function should be separate from tr click.  add an extra button and on that click add append code

Comment: TBH your code is somewhat confusing.  You intialise a global click handler multiple times within another click handler.  You have an `if` with just `;`.  `addClass` doesn't take two arguments, surprised that works at all.  You create mutliple checkboxes with the same ID.  Other than that, it looks like it should only clone the clicked row - can you convert your code to a snippet to show how it currently works?

Comment: @freedomn-m If you look closer you'll see that the `if` actually has some logic inside of it. I think it's my spacing that is confusing you here.... The first click handler is for the row click, and the second one is to remove the `highlighted` class when I click on a different row so that I don't have multiple rows highlighted at the same time. The third is in a click event which removes the highlight from any row and leaves me with no highlighted rows.

Comment: @freedomn-m my table data is coming from a controller so I'm not sure if I can put my code in a snippet as it will not generate the table data.

Comment: @AhmedSunny The reason I have in one function is because I need to append a row, which is why I have it in the tr click event.... I'm looking for a way to only process the highlighted row.

Comment: No, but you can add post-generated html to the snippet - the controller generation code isn't relevant to the question.

Comment: Have another look, the code *in the question* is `if (this.addClass("class", function() { ... })) ;`  - it's passing "class" and function() to addClass and the closing bracket to the `if` is immediately followed by `;`.  Most likely just a copy-paste to the question issue.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

> Currently if I click on a row and then click another row it will process both the rows

What is happening is when you click the row, you add a new event handler to clone that row (on clicking process).  You then click another row and it adds *another* event handler to clone the newly selected row.

When you click process, it runs both event handlers and copies both rows.

This is one of the problems of nesting event handlers.

You have two options:

1. when you add the event handler to the process button, turn off the other event handler:

   ```
   $('#ProcessList_btn').off("click").click(function() ...
   ```
2. handle the process button click outside of the row click so that it looks at highlighted rows rather than the "current" row

Snippet showing the duplicate:

```js
$(document).ready(function() {

  $('#ProcessList_btn').hide();
  $('#CancelSelection').hide();
  $('#UpdateDBRecs').hide();

  $('.MatchedTransctions tbody tr').click(function(e) {

    $("#output").append("<p>row click</p>");

    $('.MatchedTransctions tbody tr').removeClass('highlighted');
    $(this).addClass('highlighted');

    var $row1 = $(this).clone();
    var $chkbx = $('<td class="SelectedItemCHKBX"><input type="checkbox" id="SelectedItem" class="SelectedItem" /></td>');
    $('#ProcessList_btn').show();
    $('#CancelSelection').show();
    $('.SelectedtItemCHKBX').removeAttr('checked');

    $('#ProcessList_btn').click(function() {
      $("#output").append("<p>process click</p>");
      $row1.prepend($chkbx);
      $row1.appendTo('#SelectedForProcessing tbody');
      $('#UpdateDBRecs').show();
    });

    $('#CancelSelection').click(function() {
      $('.MatchedTransctions tbody tr').removeClass('highlighted');
    });
  });
})
```

```css
.highlighted {
  background-color: yellow;
}

#output {
  border: 1px solid #ccc;
}

p {
  margin: 0;
}
```

```html
<script src="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/jquery/3.3.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
<div id="MatchedTransctions" class="MatchedTransctions">
  <table class="table">
    <thead>
      <tr>
        <th>
          Id
        </th>
        <th>
          Region
        </th>
        <th>
          Person
        </th>
      </tr>
    </thead>
    <tbody>
      <tr xxxonclick="toggleClass(this,'selected');">
        <td>
          1
        </td>
        <td>
          R1
        </td>
        <td>
          P1
        </td>
      </tr>
    </tbody>

    <tr xxxonclick="toggleClass(this,'selected');">
      <td>
        2
      </td>
      <td>
        R2
      </td>
      <td>
        P2
      </td>
    </tr>

  </table>
  <div>
  </div>
</div>

<button id="ProcessList_btn" style='display:none;'>
Process
</button>

<div id="SelectedForProcessingDuplicateID">
  <table class="table" id="SelectedForProcessing">
    <thead>
      <tr>
        <th>
          Select Record
        </th>
        <th>
          Id
        </th>
        <th>
          Region
        </th>
        <th>
          Person
        </th>
      </tr>
    </thead>
    <tbody></tbody>
  </table>
</div>

<div id="output"></div>
```

Snippet using `.off`

```js
$(document).ready(function() {

  $('#ProcessList_btn').hide();
  $('#CancelSelection').hide();
  $('#UpdateDBRecs').hide();

  $('.MatchedTransctions tbody tr').click(function(e) {

    $("#output").append("<p>row click</p>");

    $('.MatchedTransctions tbody tr').removeClass('highlighted');
    $(this).addClass('highlighted');

    var $row1 = $(this).clone();
    var $chkbx = $('<td class="SelectedItemCHKBX"><input type="checkbox" id="SelectedItem" class="SelectedItem" /></td>');
    $('#ProcessList_btn').show();
    $('#CancelSelection').show();
    $('.SelectedtItemCHKBX').removeAttr('checked');

    $('#ProcessList_btn').off("click").click(function() {
      $("#output").append("<p>process click</p>");
      $row1.prepend($chkbx);
      $row1.appendTo('#SelectedForProcessing tbody');
      $('#UpdateDBRecs').show();
    });

    $('#CancelSelection').click(function() {
      $('.MatchedTransctions tbody tr').removeClass('highlighted');
    });
  });
})
```

```css
.highlighted {
  background-color: yellow;
}

#output {
  border: 1px solid #ccc;
}

p {
  margin: 0;
}
```

```html
<script src="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/jquery/3.3.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
<div id="MatchedTransctions" class="MatchedTransctions">
  <table class="table">
    <thead>
      <tr>
        <th>
          Id
        </th>
        <th>
          Region
        </th>
        <th>
          Person
        </th>
      </tr>
    </thead>
    <tbody>
      <tr xxxonclick="toggleClass(this,'selected');">
        <td>
          1
        </td>
        <td>
          R1
        </td>
        <td>
          P1
        </td>
      </tr>
    </tbody>

    <tr xxxonclick="toggleClass(this,'selected');">
      <td>
        2
      </td>
      <td>
        R2
      </td>
      <td>
        P2
      </td>
    </tr>

  </table>
  <div>
  </div>
</div>

<button id="ProcessList_btn" style='display:none;'>
    Process
    </button>

<div id="SelectedForProcessingDuplicateID">
  <table class="table" id="SelectedForProcessing">
    <thead>
      <tr>
        <th>
          Select Record
        </th>
        <th>
          Id
        </th>
        <th>
          Region
        </th>
        <th>
          Person
        </th>
      </tr>
    </thead>
    <tbody></tbody>
  </table>
</div>

<div id="output"></div>
```

Snippet to duplicate highlighted row

```js
$(document).ready(function() {

  $('#ProcessList_btn').hide();
  $('#CancelSelection').hide();
  $('#UpdateDBRecs').hide();

  $('#ProcessList_btn').click(function() {

    $("#output").append("<p>process click</p>");

    var $row1 = $('.MatchedTransctions tbody tr.highlighted').clone();
    var $chkbx = $('<td class="SelectedItemCHKBX"><input type="checkbox" id="SelectedItem" class="SelectedItem" /></td>');

    $row1.prepend($chkbx);
    $row1.appendTo('#SelectedForProcessing tbody');
    $('#UpdateDBRecs').show();
  });

  $('#CancelSelection').click(function() {
    $('.MatchedTransctions tbody tr').removeClass('highlighted');
    $('#ProcessList_btn').hide();
    $('#CancelSelection').hide();
  });

  $('.MatchedTransctions tbody tr').click(function(e) {

    $("#output").append("<p>row click</p>");

    $('.MatchedTransctions tbody tr').removeClass('highlighted');
    $(this).addClass('highlighted');

    $('#ProcessList_btn').show();
    $('#CancelSelection').show();
    $('.SelectedtItemCHKBX').removeAttr('checked');
  });
})
```

```css
.highlighted {
  background-color: yellow;
}

#output {
  border: 1px solid #ccc;
}

p {
  margin: 0;
}
```

```html
<script src="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/jquery/3.3.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
<div id="MatchedTransctions" class="MatchedTransctions">
  <table class="table">
    <thead>
      <tr>
        <th>
          Id
        </th>
        <th>
          Region
        </th>
        <th>
          Person
        </th>
      </tr>
    </thead>
    <tbody>
      <tr xxxonclick="toggleClass(this,'selected');">
        <td>
          1
        </td>
        <td>
          R1
        </td>
        <td>
          P1
        </td>
      </tr>
    </tbody>

    <tr xxxonclick="toggleClass(this,'selected');">
      <td>
        2
      </td>
      <td>
        R2
      </td>
      <td>
        P2
      </td>
    </tr>

  </table>
  <div>
  </div>
</div>

<button id="ProcessList_btn" style='display:none;'>
    Process
    </button>

<div id="SelectedForProcessingDuplicateID">
  <table class="table" id="SelectedForProcessing">
    <thead>
      <tr>
        <th>
          Select Record
        </th>
        <th>
          Id
        </th>
        <th>
          Region
        </th>
        <th>
          Person
        </th>
      </tr>
    </thead>
    <tbody></tbody>
  </table>
</div>

<div id="output"></div>
```